# iOS Bar at top resembling UINavigationBar styleBlack

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm not using a navigation controller, but I want to create a bar at the top of my UIViewController that resembles a UINavigationBar with the style of UIBarStyleBlack.

How can I do something like that?
Thanks!

iOS, xcode 4.3.3, ARC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should following this:

typically navigationBar height is `44.0f`;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.width, "your_want_height")];
    navBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;

    [[self view] addSubview:navBar];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: must `viewDidLoad` called and added above code. I edited post.